# Same volley class multiple time for API requests?

Tags: java, android, android-volley

I know volley is great to network library. My problem is I have to call API request so many times, is there a chance to call this code in a separate class and use it every time?

```
String url = "sameurl";

JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Method.POST,
        url, null,
        new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                Log.d(TAG, response.toString());

            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
            }
        }) 
// Adding request to request queue
AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonObjReq);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use listeners to do this. Move all the network and volley related code in a separate class. Pass the objects and data that it requires like URL, http method, headers etc as method parameters.

You also need to have an interface which your calling class will implement, volley will call the method of this interface to notify the caller when response is received or when request failed.

Your interface will look like this

```
public interface HttpListener {
   void onResponseReceived(JSONObject response);
   void onError(VolleyError error);
}
```

Now in your volley class you will have something like this

```
JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Method.POST,
        url, null,
        new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
                //pass httpListener instance as a method parameter to this method
                if(httpListener != null) {
                    httpListner.onResponseReceived(response);
                }

            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                if(httpListener != null) {
                    httpListner.onError(VolleyError error);
                }
            }
        })
```

You also need to pass this listener when you will make a http call. The simplest way to do this is make your caller class implement this interface and pass `this` as object of HttpListner

Your caller class will implement the HttpListener interface and override the methods. You will get a callback whenever you get a response or any error via this overridden methods.

Comment: Agreed @AbuYousuf

Comment: Your answer is good and elaborated. Do you have an example of this implementation or did use this procedure anywhere?

Comment: The answer has the implementation. You need to follow the steps. I dont have any ready-made implementation that I can share.

Comment: I think this implementation creates new instances all the time as well. When you are constructing `jsonObjReq` you need to pass the `url` every time you make a new network call and hence creating a new instance of `JsonObjectRequest`.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the idea is to call APIs over the network in a separate thread. Whenever you need to execute a network call, you need to do that in a separate thread and Volley provides a useful interface to do that in a convenient way.

Hence, whenever you create a new instance of Volley while creating a JSON request, it creates a sperate thread and starts executing the network call. The main UI thread code execution proceeds further without waiting for the network call to finish - which is the basic idea of multi-threading anyway. GC handles all the garbage collection as necessary.

If you are insisting to use the same Volley object to make all your network API calls, then you need to have the API calls in a synchronized way. That is, when a network call is returned with any response, you need to initiate the next call. This implementation depends on the situation that you are having there. If you want your network calls to be executed in an asynchronous way, then you have to create new instances of your Volley object each time you call a network API utilizing the async behaviour of multi-threaded environment.

Comment: This is true but I dont think the question talks about threading issue here. I think the question here is more oriented towards how to implement http module in a more reusable way. It is true that we can create as many instances of Volley as we want but it is not a good practice. Ideally you should abstract all this into a separate class so that if you want to change your library in future you dont have to change your app module. If we create a new instance of volley everytime we want to make a network request, then maintaining that code will be a nightmare. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: "it is true that we can create as many instances of Volley as we want but it is not a good practice." - It depends on your use case. If you need your API calls to be asynchronous, I would suggest making new instances of Volley requests each time you are calling network APIs. Otherwise, you need to have your APIs called synchronously which is a bad practice in some situation as well. I would recommend asynchronous network calls.

Comment: The class which have the volley specific implementation should handle this, whether to make new objects in every call or to reuse the same object. I would not want to clutter my application code with this.

Comment: This highly depends on how you are managing your code and using different frameworks. I do not have cluttered implementation in my case.